# Selenium tests for Google maps

Tags: selenium, google-maps-api-3, automated-tests

Does anyone have a code example for a Selenium test (or some other browser testing environment) on a Google Maps API V3 map? Specifically, I want to interact with the markers and popup windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved. Not 100% elegant but it works. Set `optimized : false` on the markers. This makes them all appear on the map ([docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions)). Then set the XPath selector in the Selenium test to `'//div[@class="gmnoprint" and @title]`, this will select all the markers. You can then interact with the markers.
See also this Google groups [posting](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/144be1bd9ad9e1f8/55298ff39a6040a4?lnk=raot).

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since this question has been answered, but I think it's nice to post here another solution that offers other possibilities that didn't exist at the time, for people that are interested in that topic

You can use [SikuliFirefoxDriver](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver) to automate Google Maps with WebDriver, with the image recognition tooling of hte great [Sikuli software](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/)