# functional tests for google maps

Tags: google-maps, testing, yii, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm trying to write functional tests and we have a customer report page with google map which we use to display reported customers on in.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779102/selenium-tests-for-google-maps) and I wondered whats the best way to write functional tests for google maps.

I am using Yii framework .

thanks guys

UPDATE:
I also have polygons, indicating regions of these customers, how are polygons displayed and how can I write tests for them?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion would be good to use Selenuim in this case. Obvoiusly there is lots of JavaScript involved and only good way how to really test it is to run tests in the webbrowser and replicate user activity.

For this you will need to install and setup [Selenium server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/):

And the use [PHPUnit Selenium extension](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html)

Comment: I'm already using selenium ide for my functional tests.but I want to know an accurate way to test my map, since there is a lot of javascript going on and also elements on the map vary in position they were last time, and also I want to know if there is a pattern in which google adds Its objects in DOM ,so I can better make my tests. thanks